# How to get Right of Future<Either<Error, List<dynamic>>> in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, future, either

I fetch data with code as below:

```
Future<Either<ResponseError, List<dynamic>>> _getResult(url) {
  return  RequestApi(url).fetchList();
}
```

I want to get List and use it to do something else, I knew how to use FutureBuilder to build Widget, but I want to try to use use Future, what can I do to get Right of Either?
I tried

Answer (score 0):

I personally use a try catch and return left or right

```
Future<Either<List<dynamic>>, Exception> _getResult(url) async {
 try {
      final response = await http.post(url);
      if (response == null) throw ResponseNullException();
      return Left(response.asList());
    } catch (e, s) {
      return Right(e);
    }
}
```